# downloading lastfinished build from teamcity

Tags: perl, teamcity

I'm using Perl's File::Fetch to download a file from the lastfinished build in Teamcity. This is working fine except the file is versioned, but I'm not getting the version number.

```
sub GetTeamcityFiles {
    my $latest_version = "C:/dowloads"
    my $uri = "http://<teamcity>/guestAuth/repository/download/bt11/.lastFinished/MyApp.{build.number}.zip";

    # fetch the uri to extract directory 
    my $ff = File::Fetch->new(uri => "$uri");
    my $where = $ff->fetch( to => "$latest_version" );
```

This gives me a file:
C:\downloads\MyApp.{build.number}.zip.

However, the name of the file downloaded has a build number in the name. Unfortunately there is no version file within the zip, so this is the only way I have of telling what file i've downloaded. Is there any way to get this build number?
c:\downloads\MyApp.12345.zip

Answer (score 0):

#### With build configs modification

If you have the ability to modify the build configs in TeamCity, you can easily embed the build number into the zip file.

- Create a new build step - choose command line
- For the script, do something like: `echo %build.number% > version.txt`
- That will put `version.txt` at the root directory of your build folder in TeamCity, which you can include in your zip later when you create it.
- You can later read that file in.

*I'm not able to access my servers right now so I don't have the exact name of the parameter, but typing `%build` will pull up a list of TeamCity parameters to choose from, and I think it is %build.number% that you're after.*

---

#### Without build configs modification

If you're not able to modify the configs, you're going to need something like egrep:

```
$ echo MyApp.12.3.4.zip | egrep -o '([0-9]+.){2}[0-9]+'
> 12.3.4

$ echo MyApp.1234.zip | egrep -o '[0-9]+'
> 1234
```

*It looks like you're running on Windows; in those cases I use [UnxUtils & UnxUpdates](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to get access to utilities like this. They're very lightweight and do not install to the registry, just add them to your system PATH.*

Comment: You are correct, I am running on windows. Unfortunately I don't have the ability to modify the configs. There are other files built, but I am not concerned with them. So perhaps there is another way of getting the last finished build? if I could dump all the zips into a directory I could then strip the version number out of the name,

Comment: I made the assumption you needed the build number, but if you just need to remove it from the file name, then it's just a matter of a simple move command. You won't care what the build number is so a simple move should take care of it; the Windows command prompt would be `move MyApp.*.zip MyApp.zip`. If you wanted to, inside your perl script, you could get a bit more complicated with the regex to handle other files; match on the pattern before the build number, and the build number .zip, and output that as the first match + .zip.

Comment: I do need the build number. What I meant is if I could strip the version number out of the name and save it in a variable, text file. Whatever. I use this build number (when doing this manually) to rename the old logs / results / install directory with the version number.  Unfortunately I'm {build.number}. I was hoping a wild card so it would just grab MyApp and save it as its true name.. so MyApp.1.2.0.4